# Designing an ngrx store for scale

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, rxjs, ngrx

This question is regarding designing ngrx stores.

I have a type of station and substation. when a substation is expanded in the main screen I show its substations and ONLY one station can be expanded at a time.

So thinking of that I make my app state like

```
export interface AppState {
  public stations: { [id: string] : Station };
  public selectedStation: string;
  public substations: { [id: string] : SubStation };
}
```

So basically each time the selectedStation is changed so does the substations via a load action that resets the data from indexeddb.
BUT then I get a requirement to move a Substation to ANOTHER Station which requires to load the target Station's Substations; Now the easier thing to do is add in

```
public targetSubstations: { [id: string] : SubStation };
```

but this seems incorrect and does not seem to scale well, what if I need to load 4 sets of substations? Then do I keep adding `targetSubstations1...4`?

So an alternative I thought of was

```
type SubstationHierarchy = {
  [stationId: string]: {
    [substationId: string]: Substation
  }
}
public substations: SubstationHierarchy;
```

This seems to scale well but my concern here is that WHILE we don't need to load all substations per stations at once this will be done when a user expands a new Station each time. So the hierarchy will ONLY grow and not be scaled down.

Keeping in mind that I haven't done any proper stress testing of how much memory can be used up by the ngrx store and am developing for the mobile what would be the most recommended approach in designing a store.

***Edit***

So we use pouchdb to asynchronously sync the data to indexeddb, you can think of this like a websocket to indexeddb connection.

For INITIAL requirements
One Station has many substations.
A user can only view one Station (and it's substations) at a time in the MAIN screen

Based on this I structure my AppState like this

```
export interface AppState {
  public stations: { [id: string] : Station };
  public selectedStation: string;
  public substations: { [id: string] : SubStation };
}
```

Where each time the selectedStation is changed I also change substations for THAT station. This works fine for most cases.

The issue comes when a user loads a separate screen (not the main screen, let's say a modal) in which he can move a substation from the `selectedStation` to a target station.

So I could change my appstate to

```
export interface AppState {
  public stations: { [id: string] : Station };
  public selectedStation: string;
  public substations: { [id: string] : SubStation };
  public targetStation: string;
  public targetSubstations: { [id: string] : SubStation };
}
```

now what if I need to allow the substation to be COPIED to TWO seperate targets, this would require me doing something along the lines of

```
export interface AppState {
  public stations: { [id: string] : Station };
  public selectedStation: string;
  public substations: { [id: string] : SubStation };
  public target1Station: string;
  public target1Substations: { [id: string] : SubStation };
  public target2Station: string;
  public target2Substations: { [id: string] : SubStation };
}
```

One option I thought of was structuring `substations` like this

```
type SubstationHierarchy = {
  [stationId: string]: {
    [substationId: string]: Substation
  }
}

export interface AppState {
  public stations: { [id: string] : Station };
  public selectedStation: string;
  public substations: SubstationHierarchy;
}
```

Where I can now store multiple substations for multiple stations. The only issue is that I am developing for mobile, and the PREVIOUS method of having target1, target2 would result in less of a memory footprint AS I replace substations, target1Substations... each time a different station is clicked, etc. However in the new structure I do not delete any data in the substations hierarchy.

Comment: It's pretty much impossible to give a __useful__ recommendation on how to structure your store without knowing all requirements and how the data should be displayed - there are so many variables in this: How many stations/substations will there be for a user? How often is the data changing/should the data be refetched everytime it is displayed? You mentioned _indexedDB_, does this mean that the data is just held locally and there is not even a server-connection? What kind of operations should be done on each model? Just a name a __few__ of the factors that all have to be take into account.

Comment: Without knowing those, you're probably best off taking a look at the ngrx-example-app and how they structure their store, they do have quite a few good practices there that can be used in many other projects as well: https://github.com/ngrx/example-app

Comment: So I edited the original question, hopefully in a more understandable manner. Also regarding indexeddb, I am actually using pouchdb which asynchronously syncs data transparently. So if someone changes the data on the backend it will get synced to the client WHERE if I need to put them to the store as well.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done for the scenario where you have dependent data is to normalize it. You can use a library like normalizr if that helps, but basically you are trying to flatten the data and then pull it back together with selectors when you need it.

I would do something like:

```
export interface AppState {
  public stations: { [id: string] : Station }; // all stations
  public selectedStation: string;
  public substations: { [id: string] : SubStation }; // all substations
}
```

Where Station is:

```
export class Station {
   id: string;
   ...
   subStationIds?: string[];
}
```

Then when you need to load a Station, you would use a selector to combine the Station with its Substations and at this point load the SubStations in the store if they aren't there.

When it comes to indexeddb and performance, I think it would depend on how big your dataset is, how much you cache, etc.